# Openlayers blank map after construction for production

Tags: openstreetmap, mapserver, openlayers

I follow [this OL tutorial](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html) to build an Openlayers app. I am very new with that sort of dev environment (nodejs/parcel).
All is working fine when in dev. OSM Tiles and MapServer Layers appear in web browser.
I built a production bundle with `npm run build`. Then I opened a web page with the `index.html` file in `/dist`. All that I got is the html part, no OSM tiles neither MapServer layers.
Here's the index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Region Centre</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.2d146de4.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="covid.6730f8ad.css"></head>
 <body> 
  <div id="maj" class="maj">blabla</div>
<div id="map"></div>  
<script src="covid.a4268f4a.js"></script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

`In covid.a4268f4a.js`, I can find the lines containing the params of Mapserver Layers for example, so html and js are linked correctly.

What did I miss?

Comment: is the OpenLayer (the lib) code included in the same JS? Maybe you need to include this JS too

Answer (score 0):

I removed a useless dependence and removed the `import...from` part in js. Now it works.